# NameError in part of code for resizing image

Tags: python, nameerror

[image: error]

I keep getting the name error repeatedly, though I do not understand what I should do further please help

Edit: [code before error part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcFF2.png)
so when i remove these four lines, the error is resolved, what was the problem?

Comment: Please check your declarations of the variables

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Several of the variables you're using aren't there. Make sure you've run all the previous cells of the notebook in order. If you've copied this specific bit of code from somewhere, you probably need to copy some more context along with it

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcFF2.png when i remove these four lines that i had added just before the erroring code, the issue is resolved. what was the problem?

Comment: @sos I'm pretty sure those lines weren't the problem. You've probably restarted the notebook, or just reexecuted part of it. The lines on the screenshot don't affect the variables you'd had issues with

Answer (score 0):

Check the variables here, many of them aren’t defined so please recheck your code. Image numbers should have be defined before the loop. What does it represent ? If it represent the images inside a directory you can write it as follows:

```
image_numbers = range(len(os.listdir(“YOUR_DIR”)))
```

Or set a number to it according to your needs.

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/zcFF2.png when i remove these four lines that i had added just before the erroring code, the issue is resolved. what was the problem?